# When I sign-in I get the username of the previous user until I reload app Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to make an app with Firebase and Flutter for a while but I noticed that when I reload or sing-up I get the username of the previous user in the Profile page.

**Code to get the username:**

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<String> getUsername() async {
    // Getting current user
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    // Getting the username
    final value = await userCol.document(currentUser.uid).get();
    final username = await value.data["username"];
    return username;
  }
```

**Code of profile page:**

```
String _username;
var dbUsername = DatabaseService().getUsername();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // getting current username
    dbUsername.then((value) {
      print(value);
      _username = value;
      return _username;
    });
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: dbUsername,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Scaffold(
                appBar: appbar.ProfileAppBar(name: _username),
                body: ...
```

**Version of dependencies**

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code so others can observe the problem. You've provided only a portion of the profile page code and with a lot of fluff. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Until you signout or clear app data the auth session exist. Try signout.

If still not working then try:

```
// Getting current user
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    await currentUser.reload();
```

Comment: i thought that this would work, but it does not unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use `authStateChanges()`, this will return stream of current user `Stream<User>`

```
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((currentUser) {
              print(currentUser); // this is give current user instantly when auth state are changed 
            });
```

Comment: For some reason i cannot use this function, perhaps i am using an older version of firebase